# Flask-JWT responce error 500 on server turnoff

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt

> Whenever i turn off server, and on again and try to access route with
>   previous token without login into app, it gives me 500 internal server
>   error instead of 'Authentication failed'. Is there any solution for
>   this.

```
@app.route('/secret_page', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def secret_page():
    print "secret page"
    return jsonify({'Success': True})
```

> error is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but try setting `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True` in your flask app config. Or look at using flask_jwt_extended, which handles this for you, and is still actively maintained. Flask_jwt which has been abandoned for a while now (full disclosure, I'm the author or flask_jet_extended).

Comment: i have blacklisted used token, to unauthorised it but after turning off server its giving 500 error msg

Comment: Are you sure the server is actually running? How are you deploying this? Do you have a web server (like nginx) in front and the flask app (like uwsgi) behind it?

Comment: Nope i am running it on flask-application

Answer (score 2):

The likely culprit is another Python extension, namely `flask_restful`, which is impacting the default Flask error handling. This error will also happen with `flask_jwt_extended` which was offered as a solution in the original answer.

If indeed you are using `flask_restful`, then alter your initialization code as so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'my_secret'
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True

# configure Flask App with Flask RESTFUL API
api = Api(app)

# configure Flask App with JWT support
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

Now the 500 error will no longer occur.